# GNU Scientific Library undefined reference to xx issue

Tags: gsl

I’m struggling with GSL, I’m on Ubuntu 14.04 and have just installed GSL. 
I downloaded the latest GSL release, and ran `./configure` in the extracted folder, then `sudo make`, and after that `sudo make install`.
Everything seems to have worked fine during the installation.

I’ve tried some basic examples from the documentation. The first example from [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/1D-Interpolation-Example-programs.html#g_t1D-Interpolation-Example-programs) page works great.

But [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/2D-Interpolation-Example-programs.html#g_t2D-Interpolation-Example-programs) example does not work. I get the following error:

```
simon@simon-bnt:~/Skrivbord/gsl-test$ gcc main.c -o main -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
/tmp/cclZjB9J.o: I funktionen "main":
main.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to gsl_interp2d_bilinear
main.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to gsl_spline2d_alloc
main.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to gsl_spline2d_set
main.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to gsl_spline2d_set
main.c:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to gsl_spline2d_set
main.c:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to gsl_spline2d_set
main.c:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to gsl_spline2d_init
main.c:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to gsl_spline2d_eval
main.c:(.text+0x308): undefined reference to gsl_spline2d_free 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I googled for a while, found another way to reference the libraries needed:

```
simon@simon-bnt:~/Skrivbord/gsl-test$ gcc -o main main.c gsl-config --cflags --libs
simon@simon-bnt:~/Skrivbord/gsl-test$ ./main
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.19: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

But as you can see that did not work either.
I’d like to be able to compile the whole program into an executable file, so I’d rather link the libraries.

I’d be really happy for all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have the `libgsl*` packages of the distribution shadowing your new installation. GSL version before 2.0 had no 2d-interpolation (IIRC) so it would explain how can compile (using your new headers) but not link.

Removing `libgsl0-dev` may be enough.  You can then still run against Ubuntu packages depending on the *run-time* but allow you to build against your local gsl 2.0.

To prove that point, here is a copy&paste from a Docker session in a Debian testing container using the *GSL 2.0* package. It then all works:

```
root@ab45b54cd90e:/tmp# gcc -o gsl_interp2d gsl_interp2d.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
root@ab45b54cd90e:/tmp# ./gsl_interp2d | head
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.010101 0.010101
0.000000 0.020202 0.020202
0.000000 0.030303 0.030303
0.000000 0.040404 0.040404
0.000000 0.050505 0.050505
0.000000 0.060606 0.060606
0.000000 0.070707 0.070707
0.000000 0.080808 0.080808
0.000000 0.090909 0.090909
root@ab45b54cd90e:/tmp#
```

I did

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libgsl-dev
apt-get install build-essential      # for gcc and friends
```

to get what is needed beyond the basic Docker container.

Comment: I removed libgsl0-dev and tried again, but unfortunately got this message:
`simon@simon-bnt:~/Skrivbord/gsl-test$ gcc main.c -o main -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`
`simon@simon-bnt:~/Skrivbord/gsl-test$ ./main`
`./main: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: What does `ldconfig -p | grep gsl` show?  Do you see 'your' library or just the system one below `/usr/lib` ?

Comment: Right now I get nothing. A bit odd.

Comment: Aha!  That means your `configure; make; sudo make install` dance did not work.  Or maybe you didn't run `ldconfig`?   Read up on how to work with dynamic libraries -- you are having a _sys.admin_ issue and not a programming issue.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll try to figure this out somehow.

Comment: The question also shows an incorrect usage of `gsl-config`, as I explained in my answer. You might want to mention that in your answer.

Comment: Yes, you did pick that up correctly but it is not the main issue---which seems to be that his installed library is not 'visible' to the dynamic linker.

Answer (score 1):

The `gsl-config` command prints arguments that are to be passed to the compiler and/or linker.  For example, on my system:

```
$ gsl-config --cflags
-I/usr/include
$ gsl-config --libs
-L/usr/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
$
```

When you type:

```
gcc -o main main.c gsl-config --cflags --libs
```

you're not passing the output of `gsl-config` to `gcc`, you're passing the *string" `gsl-config` to `gcc`, and `gcc` doesn't know what to do with it.

I think the correct command line would be this, or something very similar to it:

```
gcc $(gsl-config --cflags) main.c -o main $(gsl-config --libs)
```

This assumes you're using some sh-derived shell that recognizes the `$(...)` syntax. If your interactive shell is csh or tcsh, you can use this:

```
gcc `gsl-config --cflags` main.c -o main `gsl-config --libs`
```

(You can use the backtick syntax with bash as well, but I find the `$(...)` syntax easier to use if it's available.)

(BTW, this didn't work for me, but it's likely I just haven't installed some required package.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried the command as you wrote: `simon@simon-bnt:~/Skrivbord/gsl-test$ gsl-config --cflags`
`-I/usr/local/include`
`simon@simon-bnt:~/Skrivbord/gsl-test$ gsl-config --libs`
`-L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`
That seems to be in order.
But when i run:  `gcc $(gsl-config --cflags) main.c -o main $(gsl-config --libs)` I still get this message: `./main: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: That suggests what I was hinting at is true: you are getting _your_ GSL and the _system's_ GSL entangled.